# "Far ahead from where I am"

Tags: phrase-request

I want to get the message across that I'm not even going to worry about *step B*, unless I've gotten *step A* all figured out, and I still don't have a clue what *step A* is. I figure there are at least ten different ways to convey it, but I'm only interested in something conversational or idiomatic. Below are four sentences I've come up with. Could you correct them, if wrong?

1.*Step B* is way ahead (of where I am) right now.

2.*Step B* is too far ahead (of where I am) right now.

3.*Step B* is far too ahead (of where I am) right now.

4.*Step B* is much further ahead (of where I am) right now.

Comment: You can use any of the constructions except the one you have labelled (out of order) as 4. It would have to read: *Step B is far too **far** ahead (of where I am) right now* - inserting **far** before **ahead**.

Comment: And *much too far* would be more idiomatic than *far too far*.

Answer (score 2):

Working on the assumption that the parenthetical clause is to be included, one and two are good conversational ways to say it. Strictly speaking, 1 does not convey the message, but in conversation the meaning would be inferred. 3 is not a good sentence; I am not sure if it is grammatically valid, but it is *extremely* awkward. I believe sentence 4 is valid, but would not recommend it, as it sounds odd.

If you wanted to make the sentence shorter, you could drop either "of where I am"  or "right now" (but probably not both) from sentence 1 and it would still be natural. You could drop either or both of these phrases from sentence 2 and it would be fine.

If you wanted, you could combine sentences 1 and 2 to make "Step B is way too far ahead of where I am now," as another natural way of phrasing it.

You mentioned idiomatic expressions; there is one that illustrates exactly what you are describing, but it's usage is kind of trickey:

> "We (or I) will cross that bridge when we come to it." (many people use "get" in place of "come")

This is great as a response to a query ("what are you doing about B?" "I'll cross that bridge when I get to it."), but relies on the pronoun "that" making sense in context; as such, the preceding clause or sentence needs to make clear what "bridge" is being crossed.